# What is the name of such type of diagrams?

Tags: terminology, diagramming

I want to know what is the name of such type of diagrams? Searching for text syntax diagrams yields only railroad diagrams, but that is different type, not what I look for.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there is a specific word for them; the general term is "diagramming", as you already know. I personally would lean towards calling them "anatomies", as they break down the whole into named parts.

Comment: It's very close to what's called a "comb field" in paper form design, but really there isn't a great deal of complexity here - it's just a stylised form of bracket or curly brace such as depicted in the following link, and is a centuries-old device: https://macrotypography.blogspot.com/2015/11/curly-braces.html?m=1

Comment: They are often called decoders. [Chevy VIN decoder](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Funicfirstgr.weebly.com%2Fuploads%2F1%2F2%2F4%2F1%2F124174825%2F992774082.php&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Funicfirstgr.weebly.com%2Fblog%2Fchevy-13-digit-vin-decoder&tbnid=rML3o4iq1WcHrM&vet=12ahUKEwiTwZS8qKTwAhUD61MKHeFmA9YQMygKegUIARDHAQ..i&docid=pWlpevugYAlWuM&w=1068&h=494&q=chevy%20vin%20number%20decoder&ved=2ahUKEwiTwZS8qKTwAhUD61MKHeFmA9YQMygKegUIARDHAQ)

Answer (score 5):

I would say this is a very simple form of a "Parsing diagram".

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing):

> "Parsing, syntax analysis, or syntactic analysis is the process of
> analyzing a string of symbols, either in natural language, computer
> languages or data structures, conforming to the rules of a formal
> grammar."

Your diagram shows an expression (an e-mail address), takes its parts, and shows how it conforms to the addressing rules.

Googling for "parsing diagram", both for *All* and for *Images*, will give you examples.